# delete query of another select with left joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have to delete the results of this select.
I have tried to create a new table and insert in this the result of the select so then delete.
Who can help me?

```
select * 
from SurveySession ss (nolock)
left join
SurveySessionPages sp 
on ss.Id = sp.SurveySessionID
left join 
SurveySessionAnswers sa
on ss.Id = sa.SurveySessionID
left join 
SurveySessionAnswerChoices sac
on sa.Id = sac.SurveySessionAnswerId
left join 
SurveySessionXmlData sxd
on ss.Token = sxd.Token
where ss.StartedOn <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-365,0) 
and (ss.UpdatedOn is null or ss.UpdatedOn <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-365,0)))
```

Comment: from which table you want to delete

Comment: change the `select *` to `select <id of the field to delete>`, wrap the whole thing in parens and put a `delete from table where id in `

Comment: If you are doing this as a delete you need to stop using NOLOCK unless you don't really care if you delete all the rows or not. You can and will miss rows if you use that hint in a delete. It can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows when using it in a select statement. I would recommend not using that hint at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to answer NoDisplayName's question to get a definitive answer, but:

1. If you want to delete just from SurveySession, just change it to a delete and remove all the left joins because they are not doing any filtering of SurveySession.
2. If you want to remove one of the other tables, I would restructure the query to an inner join between surveysession and that table.
3. If you want to delete all surveysession records that meet your where criteria AND all the left joined tables that match on surveysession, you should create a delete statement for each one (a couple different ways to do this).

Comment: I would delete all rows from all tables that the select takes, thanks

Comment: Unless you do something like set up cascading deletes on your tables (which IMO are Satan's work), you need to write five delete statements. Not allowed enough characters in comments to post them all, but the four left join tables should be like this:

delete sp
from SurveySession ss 
inner join SurveySessionPages sp on ss.Id = sp.SurveySessionID
where ss.StartedOn <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-365,0) 
and (ss.UpdatedOn is null or ss.UpdatedOn <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-365,0)))

<continued>

Comment: Then after those four, delete the parent table:

delete ss from SurveySession ss 
where ss.StartedOn <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-365,0) 
and (ss.UpdatedOn is null or ss.UpdatedOn <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-365,0)))

Note: I would probably put all the SurveySession.Id values I want to delete in a temp table or table type variable beforehand and use that in the five queries, but unless you're familiar with the pros and cons of that, the straight queries are probably better to just do.

Answer (score 0):

You may use your query as a subquery and delete its results.

```
DELETE FROM SurveySession WHERE Id=(select * 
from SurveySession ss (nolock)
left join
SurveySessionPages sp 
on ss.Id = sp.SurveySessionID
left join 
SurveySessionAnswers sa
on ss.Id = sa.SurveySessionID
left join 
SurveySessionAnswerChoices sac
on sa.Id = sac.SurveySessionAnswerId
left join 
SurveySessionXmlData sxd
on ss.Token = sxd.Token
where ss.StartedOn <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-365,0) 
and (ss.UpdatedOn is null or ss.UpdatedOn <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-365,0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `delete` instead of `select` and do it like this.

```
delete SurveySession 
from SurveySession ss 
left join
SurveySessionPages sp 
on ss.Id = sp.SurveySessionID
left join 
SurveySessionAnswers sa
on ss.Id = sa.SurveySessionID
left join 
SurveySessionAnswerChoices sac
on sa.Id = sac.SurveySessionAnswerId
left join 
SurveySessionXmlData sxd
on ss.Token = sxd.Token
where ss.StartedOn <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-365,0) 
and (ss.UpdatedOn is null or ss.UpdatedOn <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-365,0)))
```